# Only Writes Last Reaction Time Set

Tags: python

I run the code and it works perfectly fine, but it only logs the last reaction time set instead of all of them. I cant seem to find whats wrong. i built another program similar to this and i checked both and compared and it still doens't work

```
#Imports
import pygame
from datetime import datetime
import time
import random
from sys import argv


#Builds PyGame Screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

black = (0, 0, 0)
x = float(2)

#For Loop
for turn in range(3):

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.display.flip()

#Delay Before The Rest Of The Program Is Runned
    time.sleep(x)

#Draws A Black Circle And Starts Runing The Reaction Program
    letter = random.randint(1, 26)

    if letter == 1:
        letter = pygame.K_a
    elif letter == 2:
        letter = pygame.K_b
    elif letter == 3:
        letter = pygame.K_c
    elif letter == 4:
        letter = pygame.K_d
    elif letter == 5:
        letter = pygame.K_e
    elif letter == 6:
        letter = pygame.K_f
    elif letter == 7:
        letter = pygame.K_g
    elif letter == 8:
        letter = pygame.K_h
    elif letter == 9:
    letter = pygame.K_i
    elif letter == 10:
        letter = pygame.K_j
    elif letter == 11:
        letter = pygame.K_k
    elif letter == 12:
        letter = pygame.K_l
    elif letter == 13:
        letter = pygame.K_m
    elif letter == 14:
        letter = pygame.K_n
    elif letter == 15:
        letter = pygame.K_o
    elif letter == 16:
        letter = pygame.K_p
    elif letter == 17:
        letter = pygame.K_q
    elif letter == 18:
        letter = pygame.K_r
    elif letter == 19:
        letter = pygame.K_s
    elif letter == 20:
        letter = pygame.K_t
    elif letter == 21:
        letter = pygame.K_u
    elif letter == 22:
        letter = pygame.K_v
    elif letter == 23:
        letter = pygame.K_w
    elif letter == 24:
        letter = pygame.K_x
    elif letter == 25:
        letter = pygame.K_y
    elif letter == 26:
        letter = pygame.K_z


    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)

    if letter == pygame.K_a:
        label= font.render("A", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_b:
        label = font.render("B", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_c:
        label = font.render("C", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_d:
        label = font.render("D", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))                
    elif letter == pygame.K_e:
        label = font.render("E", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_f:
        label = font.render("F", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_g:
        label = font.render("G", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))               
    elif letter == pygame.K_h:
        label = font.render("H", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_i:
        label = font.render("I", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_j:
        label = font.render("J", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_k:
        label = font.render("K", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_l:
        label = font.render("L", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_m:
        label = font.render("M", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_n:
        label = font.render("N", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_o:
        label = font.render("O", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_p:
        label = font.render("P", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_q:
        label = font.render("Q", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_r:
        label = font.render("R", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_s:
        label = font.render("S", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_t:
        label = font.render("T", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_u:
        label = font.render("U", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_v:
        label = font.render("V", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_w:
        label = font.render("W", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_x:
        label = font.render("X", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_y:
        label = font.render("Y", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))
    elif letter == pygame.K_z:
        label = font.render("Z", 1, black)
        screen.blit(label, (320, 240))

    #Opens Output File And Stores Reaction Times There
    reactiontimes = open("z output.txt", "w")
    pygame.display.flip()
    ReactionStart= datetime.now()
    reactiontimes.write(str(ReactionStart) + "\n")
    print (ReactionStart)

    #Checks to see if key pushed is correct
    true = True
    while true:   
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN): 
                if (event.key == letter):
                    ReactionEnd = datetime.now()
                    reactiontimes.write(str(ReactionEnd) + "\n")
                    print (ReactionEnd)
                    true = False
    #Calculates Actual Reaction Time Then Delays To Reapeat
        ReactionTime = ReactionEnd - ReactionStart
        reactiontimes.write(str(ReactionTime) + "\n")
        print(ReactionTime)


    #Closes Document
    reactiontimes.close()

    #Checks To See If Program Is Quit


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()


#
#
```

Comment: Opening a file in write mode erases whatever is already in the file.

Comment: If you want to append to a file, use `reactiontimes = open("z output.txt", "a")` instead of `reactiontimes = open("z output.txt", "w")`.

Comment: You might consider using a dict rather than that massive if/elif

Answer (score 0):

`w` overwrites your content each time you need `a` to append to your file.

```
`open("z output.txt", "a")`
```

You should also use with to open files as it closes them for you automatically:

```
`with open("z output.txt", "w") as reactiontimes:`
```